# Почему написание слов "июньский" и "день-деньской" рекомендуется запомнить?

Tags: орфография

Можно ли эти слова, а также слова "декабрьский, январский", писать по слуху? Или существует правило, объясняющее выбор мягкого знака в этих словах?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.
Если все эти слова пишутся по слуху, тогда зачем нам все эти правила - то, что пишется по слуху, правилами не нормируется. Представляете, сколько лишней информации предлагают запомнить бедным нам. Или нас Розенталь учит здесь орфоэпии? Тогда надо разделить курсы: вот орфоэпия, а вот орфография.

В связи с этим можно выдвинуть следующую гипотезу: орфографию так трудно освоить из-за того, то там много ненужных правил. Первым делом надо все написания разделить на две части: то, то можно и нужно писать по слуху, и то, что нельзя писать по слуху. Объём изучаемого материала сразу уменьшится вдвое.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Боюсь, что правила в таком виде нам очень даже "мешают" -  мягкий знак, к примеру, мы по слуху вообще разучились писать. А студенты-иностранцы должны собственные учебники иметь, не стоит на них равняться. А то получится, что ни мы, ни они орфографию не выучим. Я считаю, что это очень принципиальный вопрос. Безусловно, материал о чередовании мягких/твердых звуков интересен, но он интересен лингвистам, которые изучают эту проблему, и знакомиться с ним надо по особым книгам и в особых разделах. А чтобы правильно обозначить мягкость согласного, надо знать другую информацию, а именно она почему-то не изучается в школе. Правила по теме "Мягкий знак в середине слова" абсолютно не проработаны, зато посторонних вещей, как мы видим,  предостаточно.

Comment: Все верно. Я такие правила за правила и не считаю, я их и не сформулирую,пока, если надо, в учебник не посмотрю.

Comment: Бог с Вами, разве это правило нам мешает? Кто его учит? Русским и так понятно, что писать. Но есть ведь иностранцы, им не всегда ясно, как произносить, может, мягко (если Сибирь, то сибирьский)? Им и так проблем с шипящими хватает и с отнесением к роду. Пусть им всё будет ясно. Ну, ещё может какому студенту  для транскрипции понадобится, бывает, сомневаются. Так что пусть будет.

Comment: Дело не в иностранцах. Еще не хватало ради них орфографию изобретать.

Дэты, слова сол, фасол и вэрмышэл пышутса с мъйагкым знаком. А вылька, бутылька и тарэлька - бэз нэго. Дэты, это нэвозможно понъйать, это нада запомныт!  
  
На самом деле правило излишнее с точки зоения системы, как говорит Ларf, но в плане запоминалки оно может пригодится. Диалектные различия в произношении подобных слов весьма характерны. Сама София в другой теме это недвусмысленно дала понять ("пенсия и вензель - мягкий Н").

Answer (score 3):

Мы их и пишем по слуху, потому что правило гласит:

При образовании прилагательных с суффиксом -ск- от существительных с основой на -л и -ль (село, Урал, апрель) звук л перед суффиксом -ск- произносится мягко и поэтому после л пишется ь: сельский, уральский, апрельский. При образовании прилагательных от существительных с основой на -нь и -рь (конь, Рязань, монастырь, Сибирь) звуки н и р перед суффиксом -ск- произносятся твердо и буква ь не пишется: конский, рязанский, монастырский, сибирский, за исключением прилагательных, образованных от названий месяцев на -нь и -рь, когда буква ь остаётся: июньский (звук н произносится мягко), сентябрьский, октябрьский, ноябрьский, декабрьский, но: январский.

Или в Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке Д.Э. Розенталя , 10 изд., Москва, 2005 г.,  стр. 40 изложено так :  "Если основа имени существительного оканчивается на -нь и -рь, то перед суффиксом -ск-  мягкий знак НЕ ПИШЕТСЯ, например: конь - конский, Сибирь - сибирский."
Читаем дальше: "Исключения: прилагательные, образованные от названий месяцев: июньский, сентябрьский, октябрьский, ноябрьский, декабрьский (но: январский), а также выражение день-деньской."
( + во многих прилагательных, образованных от нерусских собственных географических названий на нь,напр.: тянь-шаньский, тайваньский, пномпеньский, торуньский, сычуаньский, тяньцзиньский)